# How to extract text from PDF WITHOUT changing the format of the text?

Tags: python, pdf, text, extract

I'm trying to extract text from multiple PDF files, however, after trying most solutions listed, I still cannot extract, line for line, text from the PDF document without the format going completely crazy. I have written the program in java and it works perfectly (code attached), please may anyone suggest how I can achieve the same task in python.

Java Code

```
File file = new File(Path);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    //Retrieving text from PDF document

    String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
```

example output:
line 1 as highlighted on pdf\n
line 2 as highlighted on pdf\n
etc.

Python Code

```
def convert_pdf_to_string(file_path):
output_string = StringIO()
with open(file_path, 'rb') as in_file:
    parser = PDFParser(in_file)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

return(output_string.getvalue())
```

#loop through files in folder and begin extracting content

```
for x in list1:
g = convert_pdf_to_string((oldDir + "\\" + x))
print(g)
```

example output:
token\n
token\n
token\n
token\n
etc.

Comment: You have two basic options.  1. Write your own PDF parser in python. 2. Find a PDF parser that someone has already written, the equivalent of the PDFTextStripper your Java code uses, but in python.

Comment: @rossum I have tried most of the PDF libraries out there, so I guess if I can't find something that will solve this problem building a parser will be my only option.